# Converting a Multi to Uni<Void> on completion

Tags: mutiny

What is the most suitable way to convert a Multi to Uni on completion?
So far, I have the following working solutions:

```
multi.collect().asList().replaceWithVoid()
```

It just feels a bit odd to collect the items and to replace the list when I'm only interested in receiving an item upon completion. Am I missing a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply skip all `Multi` emitted items then switch over to a `Uni`:

```
multi.skip()
     .where(ignored -> true)
     .toUni()
     //.replaceWithVoid()
```

Optionally using the `Uni#replaceWithVoid` as you suggested to switch the `Uni` formal type.

The difference would be to avoid storing elements temporarily in memory using the `Multi#collect` operator. Now you are simply ignoring the items and switching downstream on completion.